# I don't know what i am doing wrong, I want to change the background color of the navbar when the page gets scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

This is what i am doing, I used bootstrap to style this nav. The nav basically collapses and a toggle button appears.

```
<nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark py-0 fixed-top ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CANDY</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01"
                aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                class="btn btn-info">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">TICKETS</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>
```

this is the css for styling it when scrolled. Nothing else was used to style it

```
#mainNavbar.scrolled{
    background-color: #ac3bac;
    transition: background 500ms;
}
```

But the problem is that it isn't toggling the class 'scrolled' to style it. I have tried multiple approaches but none of them are working. If possible pls help me complete it

```
<script>enter code here
        $(function () {
            $(document).scroll(function () {
                var $nav = $("#mainNavbar");
                $nav.toggleClass("scrolled", $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: remove `navbar-dark` class from nav tag.

Comment: Do you get errors?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code [here](https://codepen.io/tigna/pen/qBXoLON), which i hope it will help you to focus on your problem.

I have add some lorem in order to make the window scroll properly, in order to trigger the event.

HTML:

```html
<nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark py-0 fixed-top ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CANDY</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01"
                aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                class="btn btn-info">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">TICKETS</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>
<!--tags below are only there in order to fill the space in order to obtain the scrollbar-->
<div class="grid">
    <div class="el">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="el">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="el">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="el">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="el">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="el">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="el">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="el">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="el">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="el">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="el">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="el">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}

#mainNavbar.scrolled{
    background-color: #ac3bac;
    transition: background 500ms;
}

/* This is in order to obtain a scrollable view in the example */
.grid{
  display: grid;
}

.el{
  height: 20vh;
}
```

JS

```js
  $(function () {
            $(document).scroll(function () {
                var $nav = $("#mainNavbar");
                $nav.toggleClass("scrolled", $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
            });
        });
```

Everything should work fine, are you sure have you add all the proper scripts?

Comment: Please add your code to your answer, because links might get broken at some point and then your answer would become meaningless. Even though it is correct.

Comment: @LajosArpad you're right, i hope like that it will be fine

Comment: Francesco, it's fine now, I have upvoted it. Thanks!